# Alternative to T4 templates for generating c# enums/dictionaries from SQL tables

Tags: c#

Are there any alternative ways to script/generate C# enums and dictionaries from SQL tables?

Our t4 templates have been giving us issues off and on fairly consistently and it's beginning to look more appealing to pursue alternatives rather than spending a day every so often troubleshooting the newest quirk.

Comment: You can use an ORM like EF or a microORM like Dapper so you *don't* have to generate anything.

Comment: There's always `StringBuilder`.